# getAccount() in web3 produce two different errors on two different browsers

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am trying to follow a tutorial and keep getting two different errors:

on chrome:

> "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of
>   undefined"

on Firefox:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): web3.eth.getAccounts(...) is undefined

my code is simple, it's a react project with localhost provider using Ganache and npm:

```
 async loadBlockchainData(){
  const web3 = await window.web3
  const acc = await web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);      
  this.setState({account: acc[0]})
```

Why does getAccounts returning undefined in the first place? and why chrome is producing this error while firefox is not?

my metamask is logged in in both browsers (and accepted the conntection)

web3 version is web3@1.0.0-beta.55

EDIT: 
here is how I initialized web3:

```
 async componentWillMount(){
 await this.loadWeb3();
 await this.loadBlockchainData();
    }    
  async loadWeb3() {

   window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
     if (window.ethereum) {
       window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
       await window.ethereum.enable();

     } 

     else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

     }

     else {
      console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
     }
   });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probable cause is that you are not initializing `web3` correctly. If you are using `metamask` then initialize `web3` like so:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

And at the start of file import `Web3`.

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Also be extra careful about not to mix upper case `Web3` with lower case `web3`.

**Edit after question edit and comment**

I don't know which tutorial you are following. But you don't have to `await` on `window.web3` in `loadBlockchainData()` and you dont have to `listen` on window load in `loadWeb3()`.

Simplified `loadWeb3()`

```
async loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
    } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log("Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!");
    }
}
```

and `loadBlockchainData()`

```
async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const acc = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    this.setState({ account: acc[0] });
}
```

web3 version 1.2.1 and  react version 16.10.2

Comment: I followed an online tutorial and the teacher is getting a correct output. 
I will update my post with my web3 initialization

Answer (score 0):

I got same error following dapp university tutorial.  This can be fix by copying http://localhost:3000/ into a chrome browser that has metaMask.  Then the web page is shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

window.web3 is removed by metamask. now everything can be done with window.ethereum - [web3 removal link by metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#summary-of-breaking-changes)

Below is the new way of getting accounts.

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
```

initialize ethereum provider

```
async loadWeb3() {
const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()

if (provider) {
  console.log('Ethereum successfully detected!')
  // From now on, this should always be true:
  // provider === window.ethereum

  // Access the decentralized web!

  // Legacy providers may only have ethereum.sendAsync
  const chainId = await provider.request({
    method: 'eth_chainId'
  })
} else {
  // if the provider is not detected, detectEthereumProvider resolves to null
  console.error('Please install MetaMask!' )
}
}
```

Here is how you can access the accounts:

```
async loadWeb3Accounts() {
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
console.log(accounts[0]);}
```